# Убрать последний пункт навигации для fullPage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть именно такая разметка + fullPage плагин с dots навигацией:

```js
var counterScreen = 0,
    counterScreenList = [];

// $("#fullpage > div").each(function() {
//   var elem = $(this).attr("data-anchor");


//   console.log(elem);

//   if(elem !== undefined || elem !== null) {
//     counterScreenList.push(elem);
//     counterScreen++
//   }
// });

$("#fullpage").fullpage({
  licenseKey: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx',
  anchors: counterScreenList,
  lazyLoading: !0,
  navigation: !0,
  navigationPosition: "right",
  navigationTooltips: counterScreenList,
  showActiveTooltip: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.4/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha256-MEURuTYmXMgJUKFGPHlPu7NKXWTA2PMhMIaM+OZhE84=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.4/fullpage.extensions.min.js" integrity="sha256-hpQQQJNPOw2uF6eylQqhnNkjQWl8F7FVGx3WyYkdqKI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" data-anchor="S-1">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" data-anchor="S-2">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" data-anchor="S-3">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Вопрос:** как убрать 4-ую точку навигации с помощью js (именно js а не стилями!) для 4-ой секции с `data-anchor="undefined"` ?

Comment: а секцию убирать надо?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, нет

Comment: это не подходит, правильно понимаю? https://codepen.io/mihinov/pen/XWmZoxY

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, правильно! "Есть именно такая разметка" !!!

Comment: добавь ссылку на документацию к плагину

Comment: и почему не стилями убрать?

Comment: @Grundy, https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/lang/russian#fullpagejs

Comment: @Grundy, потому что не стилями!)

Comment: в общем в самой библиотеке это никак не реализуется: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/src/fullpage.js#L1077 как отсюда видно просто идет цикл по секциям, и добавляется `anchor`. Плюс не совсем понятно что делать если anchor будет пропущен не у последнего элемента

Comment: @Grundy, "Плюс не совсем понятно что делать если anchor будет пропущен не у последнего элемента" ... ))) that's I am here )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107728/discussion-between-grundy-and-hamster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var counterScreen = 0,
  counterScreenList = [];

$("#fullpage").fullpage({
  licenseKey: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx',
  anchors: counterScreenList,
  lazyLoading: !0,
  navigation: !0,
  navigationPosition: "right",
  navigationTooltips: counterScreenList,
  showActiveTooltip: true,
});

$('#fp-nav li a[href="#undefined"]').last().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.4/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha256-MEURuTYmXMgJUKFGPHlPu7NKXWTA2PMhMIaM+OZhE84=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.4/fullpage.extensions.min.js" integrity="sha256-hpQQQJNPOw2uF6eylQqhnNkjQWl8F7FVGx3WyYkdqKI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" data-anchor="S-1">
    <h2>1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" data-anchor="S-2">
    <h2>2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" data-anchor="S-3">
    <h2>3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```